# sql where clause for each row of a subquery

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, subquery

I have 2 tables in MSSql

table_a:

```
data|id_1|timeInIntForm
------------------------------
data1 | 1/22323/3 | 1433721600
data2 | 1/22323/3 | 1433721660
```

and I have another table

table_b

```
data|(string list of ids)|startTimeinIntform|EndTimeInIntForm
--------------------------------------------------------------
dataA| (a_1223233_z a_1223233_x) | 1433721601 | 1433721659
datab| (a_1223233_z a_1223233_x) | 1433721602 | 1433721645
```

I want to do a

```
select * from table_a where id_1 = 'someId' 
and timeInIntForm between 'time1' and 'time2' 
and not between TableB_row1[startTimeinIntform] and TableB_row1[EndTimeInIntForm]'
.
.
.
and not between TableB_rowN[startTimeinIntform] and TableB_rowN[EndTimeInIntForm]'
```

The ids do not match but can be correlated on a different table that has

table_c:

```
data|id_1|id_2
-----------------------------
data| 1/22323/3 | a_1223233_z
data| 1/22323/4 | a_1223233_x
```

my initial thought is in PHP to get the rows from table_b and then as I select from table_a build the not between clause from each row in table_b. But I would LOVE to do this in one select statement if possible. Any ideas?

I edited it to have some "sample" data I was asked for. I am stumped on how to join these .. I admit freely I am not a pro or even poor at joins but I am really stumped on how to join table b to a and c

Comment: Have you heard of `JOIN`? http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help explain the problem.  Consider a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: I added some sample data, I am sorry IDs in Table_a are not in a form that I can join them on table_b, even using table_c i do not think. And unfortunatly I do not have a lot of power over that .

Answer (score 0):

Well I am not sure exactly without the tables but I think this would do it.

```
Select a.*
From table_a a
join table_c c
on a.ID_1 = c.ID_1
join table_b b
on c.ID_2 = b.ID_2
Where a.ID_1 = 'someid'
and a.timeinintform not between 'time1' and 'time2'
and a.timeinintform not between b.starttimeininform and b.endtimeinintform
```

Comment: I was thinking that but the ids on table_b is a string with space delimited list of ids from table_c